# Linq Take on Include?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a query with a lot of includes,  and I'm wondering if I can do Takes on some of the includes.

For example, here's one of my queries,  with the (illegal) Take illustrating what I want to do.

```
var primaryLocation = context.Locations
                .Include("PhoneNumbers")
                .Include("Invoices").Take(50)
                .Include("Invoices.Items")
                .Include("Schedules")
                .Include("Staffs")
                .SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == locationId);
```

Currently the only way I can think to do it would be like so:

```
var primaryLocation = context.Locations
                .Include("Invoices")
                .Include("Etc")
                .SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == locationId);

primaryLocation.Invoices = primaryLocation.Invoices.Take(50).ToList();
```

I'd prefer not doing it that way, since means pulling back the entire Invoice list from the database, which I don't need.

Is there a handy way to build the Take into my query?

Comment: What are you using to translate the linq to your server? linq2sql, entity framework, or something else?

Comment: What SQL does it generate for the 2nd part?

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546148/1832856) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like have two conflicting criteria for what you're doing. I'm guessing here, but you didn't leave us all that much to go on.

Since your `primaryLocation.Invoices = primaryLocation.Invoices.Take(50).ToList();` statement only makes use of 1 of your includes, I'm assuming you're doing more things with your `primaryLocation` than what you've shown us. This leads me to believe that you want that primaryLocation to include all of the stuff. And then you seem not to want more than those 50, so that's not all of the stuff after all then... To me this is a contradiction. If you require all, you should include it all.

If you want your 50 invoices selection specifically you could get those separately in its own query. I use NHibernate myself, so I'm not sure of the syntax for future's in Entity framework, but if you want to ask for multiple things with only 1 round-trip to the server, in NHibernate you can make a series of queries into futures to allow this. I expect Entity framework has something similar.

In short, what I'm suggesting is that if you want primaryLocation to include all of your data, then that's what you'll get, and if you're after more specific information with filters like Take, then you might want to query more specifically.

Comment: This query is the initial page load data for a SPA app,  so I'm pulling down a pretty full set of data,  but obviously don't need the entire historical set for some types.

Comment: That's my point. You need to decide. Are you pulling the whole thing, or not? If not then you need to split up your query into smaller more specific queries.

Comment: So the answer to my question is no,  there's no way to build those filters into the single initial query

Comment: That would be my guess. At least, afaik, that's how it is for NHibernate, which is a rather equivalent ORM. But then, I've been wrong before...

Answer (score 0):

Use projection instead of blindly calling `Include` if you don't want everything:

```
var primaryLocation = context.Locations
    .Select(location => new {
        Id = location.Id,
        Name = location.Name,
        // ... other properties needed on the front end
        RecentInvoices = location.Invoices
            // really should sort if you're only taking 50
            .OrderByDescending(invoice => invoice.CreatedAt)
            .Take(50),
        AllPhoneNumbers = location.PhoneNumbers,
    })
    .SingleOrDefault(location => location.Id == locationId);
```

You could use projection to get just the invoice information you need too, I just didn't want to over-complicate the example.

Using this method you get exactly the data you want without adding confusion. It also allows you to name your properties (such as `RecentInvoices` above) to add more meaning.