# Take subset of included collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to only take the first 20 entries of an included collection. Example:

```
var teamsWithTeamMembers = (from t in db.Teams
      orderby t.Name
      select t)
     .Include("TeamMembers")
```

I want only 20 of the first Teams, and for each Team I only want the first 20 Team members. `Take(20)` works for Teams, but I cannot figure out how to only take 20 of the Team members

Comment: Look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545428/how-to-limit-number-of-related-data-with-include seems similar.

Comment: My bad, I was searching with the wrong terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here

- Projecting your query using an anonymous type (as my example) or a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO):

  ```
  var teamsWithTeamMembers= db.Teams.OrderBy(t=>t.Name)
                               .Select(e=>new {e.Name,Team=e.TeamMembers.OrderBy(p => p.SomeProperty).Take(20)})
                               .Take(20);
  ```
- Using explicit loading:

  ```
  var teams= db.Teams.OrderBy(t=>t.Name);
  ```

  Then:

  ```
  foreach(var t in teams )//be careful here, a round trip to your DB per each team
  {
   context.Entry(t) 
      .Collection(b => b.TeamMembers) 
      .Query() 
      .OrderBy(p => p.SomeProperty).Take(20)
      .Load(); 
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Wish there was a nicer way though :)